# How to convert a Json String into a NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch, restkit

I am currently trying to convert the JSON Representation of some Objects into an *NSArray*.
I used **RestKit** to get the Response through our API and now I want to convert the *RKResponse* into an Array of Objects. How can I do this ?

Comment: Is there any delimeter to distinguish between your object string? Post an example response.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
 NSData* data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *values = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];  // if you are expecting  the JSON string to be in form of array else use NSDictionary instead
```

The above code works good for iOS 5 and above

Comment: Ok maybe i should describe my problem a little bit more detailed. I got an Array of Json Objects in form of a RKRESPONSE and now i want to convert it into an Array with real Objective -C Objects with propertys and so one ...

Comment: What is the dataType of RKRESPONSE.Is it NSDATA or some other??

Comment: RKRESPONSE is defined inside the RestKit Headers. It has its own Type.

Comment: I can convert it to a string like the following :                 NSData *tempWishes = [[response bodyAsString]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: so just use bypass the first line of my answer and subject tempWishes instead of 'data' for JSONSerialization.The output should be an array

Comment: is it an array of NSDictionaries??

Comment: Works fine, and pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try importing RestKit/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h. Then use try the method objectFromString:error:. To get a NSDictionary representation. From the NSDictionary you can get the array.